# Merge Vs Update in SQLServer for small tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-merge

I have two small tables (~3K rows) and I have to update data in one table from the other table. I can perform the required operations with both MERGE and UPDATE statements. Which one should I prefer to use? And what if I have to support scalablity also i.e. the tables can grow in future.

Comment: `MERGE` = `UPDATE` + `INSERT`.  If you aren't doing any inserts than just use an UPDATE.  Both scale about equally.

Comment: What semantics do you want if there are multiple possible source rows to a single target row? Undeterministic results or an error message?

Comment: Like @DStanley said, `MERGE` is generally used to perform both update and insert. So, a simple join update might suffice in your scenario.